# G++ compiler object code: why data variables are assigned memory address of 0

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, compiler-construction, g++

I tried to compile my simple C++ source code with the following Linux command
**$g++ -c foo.cpp** to generate an object file. I realized that all the macro variables that I have created are assigned a memory address of 0. What is the reasoning behind this? Why doesn't the assembler just assigned the appropriate amount of memory to the variables.

Edit:

The following is the code that I used:

> **$g++ -c -g string.cpp**
>
> **$objdump -dS string.o > string.o.text**

The following is my simple C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define STRING "string\n"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int count = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout<< STRING;
    return 0;
}
```

One of the lines on my string.o.txt said:
[image: Snapshot of part of my object file]

The callq has a memory address of 0.

Comment: Show the code and assembler output.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and provide [MCVE]

Comment: That's almost definitely not what's happening.

Comment: What's 0 is the address of the function, not of the argument. Since the function is not defined in this translation unit, it will need to be filled in later.

Answer (score 2):

The 0s in the assembly listing are just a placeholder.  The linker will fill in more of the address (generally an offset from the start of the data segment), then the loader will adjust those offsets with the address the image was loaded to.